# Django REST framework: create JSON fragments from string

Tags: django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to store JSON fragments in TextField of my model with JSON:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    people = models.TextField()
```

I have serializer class:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('name', 'people')
```

How can I told Django REST Framework to treat people string like JSON, not like string. E.g. when people is [ {"name":"A", "surname":"B"}] I want have in JSON generated by Django REST framework

```
"people" : [ {"name":"A", "surname":"B"}]
```

and not

```
"people" : "[ {\"name\":\"A\", \"surname\":\"B\"}]"
```

---

Edit: I change ASerializer class and used JSONField from django-jsonfield and everything works. New code below, transform_people method serves to serialization and validate_people to deserialization:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def transform_people(self, obj, value):
        if obj is None:
            return obj
        else:
            return obj.people

    def validate_people(self, attrs, source):
        return attrs

    class Meta:
        model = A
```

Comment: I answered this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156403/django-rest-framework-how-do-i-serialize-a-field-that-already-contains-json/22294986#22294986)

Comment: Thanks! I edited my answer to show solution

Answer (score 3):

Convert your response to json object

```
import json
## In this case lets say
response = [{"name":"A", "surname":"B"}]
data = json.dumps(response)
print data
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`serializers.JSONField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield)

```
class ASerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    people = serializers.JSONField()

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('name', 'people')
```