# How to serve TextField as literal JSON without escaping with Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

We're storing raw JSON data in our model via a TextField and would like that data to be served by the REST Framework API.

The content is gettings escaped and rendered as a string rather than as part of the object. e.g. `{\r\n  \"phases\": [\r\n    \"S` etc

from `requirements.txt`

```
    Django==1.8.2
    djangorestframework==3.1.3
```

[image: Screenshot for reference.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added the following to my serializer (and `import json` at the top of my urls.py)

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
  ret = super(RoadmapSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
  ret['jsonField'] = json.loads(ret['jsonField'])
  return ret
```

nb: `jsonField` is the name of the model attribute declared in `models.py`

```
jsonField = models.TextField(verbose_name="JSON", blank=True)
```

Sources of inspiration
- [django-rest-framework: How Do I Serialize a Field That Already Contains JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156403/django-rest-framework-how-do-i-serialize-a-field-that-already-contains-json/22294986#22294986) (answers by Almalki and Denis Cornehl)
- http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#serializers (since transform_ was deprecated in drf 3.0)